# Using single line chart with multiple, unrelated, data sets?

Tags: data-visualization, dataset

I would like to visualize two unrelated sets of data using a single line chart to check for any "correlation" (it's just for fun - nothing that claims to be statistically accurate).

Just as an example: Let's say I want to display how many calories a person eats each week and compare it to his/her weight each week.

Since one of the data sets uses calories and the other uses kilograms/pounds, what is the best way to visualize this using a single line chart? Dual y-axis? Using the deviation from the mean value?

Comment: Dual axes plots is a very bad idea. See Stephen Few’s explanation of why here: http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/dual-scaled_axes.pdf Unless the time dimension is *very* important, I would just use a normal scatterplot. If it *is* important, try using a series of scatterplots, each showing a different time period. It can also be useful to let the time periods be partially overlapping. For an example of how this would look, try `example(coplot)` in R. (The variable `depth` here would correspond to *time* in your example.)

Comment: I really like this answer. Yes, try using a scatterplot, with x:y aspect ratio 1:1 to assess correlation, and a sliding window (or static coplot) to look for local correlation. Hadley Wickham's ggplot2 package makes it very difficult to use dual axes, for a reason.